# Where can I find boundaries of all German voting districts in federal elections (since 1949)?

Tags: data-request, germany, district

I am looking for shapefiles containing the boundaries of all voting districts in German federal elections, 1949-2021. I appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here:
https://www.bundeswahlleiter.de/en/bundestagswahlen/2017/wahlkreiseinteilung/downloads.html

Or some other EU data portals like this :

https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/main/data/database